# DocuSign Standard account - Integration key

Tags: docusignapi

I have activated Docusign Standard account but I am not able to find option to generate integratory key.
First I have tried demo account and that was working,but in developer account I am not able to find.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You create integration keys in the developer sandbox's admin tool using the **API and Keys** screen (see the bottom left navigation bar).

Start at https://demo.docusign.net and then goto the admin tool.

Here are videos that show how to create an integration key:

- [Authorization Code Grant integration key](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiRI4fe5HgM&list=PLllMTiuDU7qagj8d78cCDOLpxkvVTdufw&index=10&t=0s)
- [JWT Grant integration key](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55j4eZLK5Hg&list=PLllMTiuDU7qagj8d78cCDOLpxkvVTdufw&index=8&t=0s)

You then develop your application in demo. When you're ready for production, use the [Go Live process](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live).

Comment: I have followed process and able to generate key.Now issue is it is giving me error. Error while requesting an access token: POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token returned a response status of 400 Bad Request

Comment: @Sanjay, please open a new question.

Comment: I have created project. https://gitlab.com/sanju24689/docusign . Here DocuSignExample is working but DocuSignExample1 is not working.

Comment: @Sanjay, please create a new stackoverflow question for your new issue. Thank you.

Comment: Created.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869379/java-and-docusign-integration