# Java And Docusign Integration

Tags: docusignapi

I have created integrator key and private/public key in docusign sandbox.

When I am trying to call api,it is giving me error.

My code is like this:

```
public class DocuSignExample1 {

    private static final String IntegratorKey = "10048d4c-0549-434e-b224-4805b36b69e1";
    private static final String UserId = "ef27e777-c6fc-4385-91ce-63dafab5385b";
    private static final String privateKeyFullPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/keys/docusign_private_key2.txt";


    private static final String Recipient = "xxx@gmail.com";
    private static final String SignTest1File = "/src/test/docs/SignTest1.pdf";
    private static final String BaseUrl = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] fileBytes = null;
        try {
            String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

            Path path = Paths.get(currentDir + SignTest1File);
            fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        } catch (IOException ioExcp) {
            ioExcp.printStackTrace();
        }

        EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        envDef.setEmailSubject("Please Sign My Sample Document");
        envDef.setEmailBlurb("Hello, Please Sign My Sample Document.");

        Document doc = new Document();
        String base64Doc = Base64.encodeToString(fileBytes, false);
        doc.setDocumentBase64(base64Doc);
        doc.setName("TestFile.pdf");
        doc.setDocumentId("1");

        List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Document>();
        docs.add(doc);
        envDef.setDocuments(docs);

        Signer signer = new Signer();
        signer.setEmail(Recipient);
        signer.setName("Sanjay");
        signer.setRecipientId("1");
        envDef.setRecipients(new Recipients());
        envDef.getRecipients().setSigners(new ArrayList<Signer>());
        envDef.getRecipients().getSigners().add(signer);
        envDef.setStatus("sent");

        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(BaseUrl);
        try {
            byte[] privateKeyBytes = null;
            try {
                privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(privateKeyFullPath));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (privateKeyBytes == null)
                return;
            java.util.List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
            scopes.add(OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE);
            OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(IntegratorKey, UserId, scopes, privateKeyBytes,
                    3600);
            apiClient.setAccessToken(oAuthToken.getAccessToken(), oAuthToken.getExpiresIn());
            UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(oAuthToken.getAccessToken());
            apiClient.setBasePath(userInfo.getAccounts().get(0).getBaseUri() + "/restapi");
            Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);
            String accountId = userInfo.getAccounts().get(0).getAccountId();
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
            EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
            System.out.println("EnvelopeSummary: " + envelopeSummary);
        } catch (ApiException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In above code I am just changing my account key,but not working.

I have created project with example.
Here DocusignExample.java is working but DocusignExample1.java
is not working.

https://gitlab.com/sanju24689/docusign

For DocusignExample,I have taken reference(key) from docusign java sdk(https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/SdkUnitTests.java)
With that reference i have created my code and just change integratory key,api username and private key.

It's giving me error like "com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting an access token: POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token returned a response status of 400 Bad Request"

Comment: Please don't link us to an external site. Make a [mcve] or show the relevant portions of the code and the problem. You should probably already know [ask] a question.

Comment: Have you done given User Consent to your IK, as documented in Step1 of [JWT docs(https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken)

Comment: I am using silent login through backend(spring).

Answer (score 0):

So you have a working example but then when you change the integration key the example stops working?

Sounds like a problem with your settings: check that you're using the right RSA Private key with the right Integration Key (IK).

Also check that the IK does NOT have "Mobile app" checked.

Comment: Look like Something that.Might be I am mmissing something. Here I have attached configuration file.please check and guide me. https://gitlab.com/sanju24689/docusign/blob/master/download1.png and download2.png

Comment: After you made changes to the Integration Key, did you wait 10 minutes and try again? It can take up to 10 minutes for changes to an IK to propagate throughout the DocuSign system. 

If the eg-01-java-jwt app works with one IK but not with another then clearly the problem is with the new IK. Also make sure that you copied all of the private key into the configuration file.

Comment: I haven't created working IK.I have tested with java-sdk client given key(https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/SdkUnitTests.java)

Comment: See if my [IK for JWT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55j4eZLK5Hg) is of help. Sounds like you have a problem created the integration key. Also check out my video on the [JWT example for Node](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqpj5j_oXU8). Java example is similar.

Comment: I am doing same thing.still not succeed.